# How do I determine the optimal number of tasks to submit for my architecture?

Tags: java, concurrency

I understand that for a CPU-bound task that you typically want 1 thread per core, otherwise you can start adding more threads per core. But what about *tasks per thread* (or are they one in the same)?

I'm trying to figure out how to chunk up a big problem into the optimal number of `Runnable`s, so that I can submit them to an `Executor`. My understanding is that you can then configure the number of threads the `Executor` will use (so its not necessarily 1 to 1).

So my question is: let's say I find that for my given application I determine that 5 threads per core is the optimal ratio; **but how do I determine the optimal number of tasks (`Runnables`) to create in the first place?**

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489388/platform-independent-way-of-detecting-the-number-of-processors-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make it a knob that you can change until you're happy. What may work for your workstation may not work for the deployment server. It depends. Grab the knob in one hand and a stopwatch in the other, and benchmark it until you're happy with the results.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know the **law of Amdahl** ?

With this formula you can determine the potential *speedup* your *multi-threaded* application will gain compared to as it would be *single-threaded*.

[Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

To sum up you have the following formula:

**Speedup** = *1 / (1 - p) + (p / n)*

where

**p** is the parallel fraction,
**1 - p** is the sequential fraction and
**n** is the number of processors.

If you have an application that consists of 60 % concurrent code and 40% sequential code you would have a parallel fraction of 0.6 and a sequential one of 0.4.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Marc that is helpful but doesn't really answer the question. One uses Amadahl's Law to *help* determine whether or not multi-threading will help solve your problem, but my question pre-supposes you've already decided to multi-thread. What I'm asking is: *how do I determine the number of `Runnable`s to submit to an `Executor`*, which is not necessarily the same as the question of *how many threads per core*. Thanks again for the help though.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you for your gentle response.